# How to change style scrollable tab in React-native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-ios, native-base

I am using Native-Bae in my project and already added those style elements for the scrollable tab but it's not changing the color as I need. Here is my code.

```
<Tabs styles={{tabBarUnderlineStyle:'#0dc49d',tabBarActiveTextColor:'#0dc49d',tabBarInactiveTextColor:'#D3D3D3'}} >

   <Tab  heading="Most Popular">
     <Articles />
   </Tab>
   <Tab heading="New">
     <ArticlesNew />
   </Tab>
 </Tabs>
```

It shows default blue color while  I need to change underline color, active text color to green and inactive text color to gray.

Answer (score 2):

i have try your code, and got this solution, 
first is change properties of your `Tabs` if you want change the underline style :

```
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor:'#0dc49d' }} >
```

and then change style properties of your tab using this code :

```
<Tab  heading="Most Popular" activeTextStyle={{ color:'#0dc49d' }} textStyle={{ color:'grey' }} >
```

and your full code is should be like this :

```
<Tabs tabBarUnderlineStyle={{ backgroundColor:'#0dc49d' }} >

   <Tab  heading="Most Popular" activeTextStyle={{ color:'#0dc49d' }} textStyle={{ color:'grey' }} >
     <Articles />
   </Tab>
   <Tab heading="New" activeTextStyle={{ color:'#0dc49d' }} textStyle={{ color:'grey' }} >
     <ArticlesNew />
   </Tab>
 </Tabs>
```

Hope can help your problem, please notice me if you have an error, thanks :)

Comment: Thanks for your help. This code works. Do you know is there any way to use a border instead of tab underline? I am asking it because tab underline is like border bottom only.

Comment: you can use another properties in tabs native base i think

Comment: Above code worked for changing the color. Thanks a lot.

Comment: you're welcome :) if you feel my answer is helping you solved your problem, you can mark my answer as checked so another people can try my code too :)